# How to send email by selecting the name in ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a schedule finder vba UserForm.  I want to be able to send an an email template to whoever I choose in the listbox. After selecting a name in listbox, I can then click the send button and then a template ready to be send to that person.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
'Dim mySheet As Worksheet
'Dim myUser As Range

Private Sub cmbRestDay_Change()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet    'declaring mySheet as the Worksheet...
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Set mySheet = Sheets("Dashboard")
ListBox1.Clear
x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns(2), cmbRestDay.Value) > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(i, 2) = cmbRestDay.Value Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    ListBox1.List = dict.keys
Else
    ListBox1.AddItem "Match not found"
End If


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

cmbRestDay.Clear

With cmbRestDay
    .AddItem ("Mon")
    .AddItem ("Tue")
    .AddItem ("Wed")
    .AddItem ("Thu")
    .AddItem ("Fri")
    .AddItem ("Sat")
    .AddItem ("Sun")
End With

With cmbMyRD
    .AddItem ("Mon")
    .AddItem ("Tue")
    .AddItem ("Wed")
    .AddItem ("Thu")
    .AddItem ("Fri")
    .AddItem ("Sat")
    .AddItem ("Sun")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you are stuck? What exactly is it that you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Name of the Send Email CommandButton is **cmdSendEmail** then place the following code on the UserForm Module.

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet    'declaring mySheet as the Worksheet...

Private Sub cmdSendEmail_Click()
Dim Agent As String
Dim EmailID As String
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim Str As String
Dim i As Long, r As Long
With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Agent = .List(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
If Agent = "" Then
    MsgBox "No agent was selected in the ListBox.", vbExclamation, "Agent Not Selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If
r = Application.Match(Agent, mySheet.Columns(1), 0)
EmailID = mySheet.Range("D" & r).Value

Str = "Hi " & Agent & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Str = Str & "I would like to swap my Mon shedule to your Sunday schedule. & vbnewline & vbnewline"
Str = Str & "More Power" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Str = Str & "Thanks," & vbNewLine & "Bill"

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    .To = EmailID
    .Subject = "Hi " & Agent
    .Body = Str
    .Display
    '.Send
End With
Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub cmbRestDay_Change()
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Set mySheet = Sheets("Dashboard")
ListBox1.Clear
x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns(2), cmbRestDay.Value) > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(i, 2) = cmbRestDay.Value Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    ListBox1.List = dict.keys
Else
    ListBox1.AddItem "Match not found"
End If


End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

cmbRestDay.Clear

With cmbRestDay
    .AddItem ("Mon")
    .AddItem ("Tue")
    .AddItem ("Wed")
    .AddItem ("Thu")
    .AddItem ("Fri")
    .AddItem ("Sat")
    .AddItem ("Sun")
End With

With cmbMyRD
    .AddItem ("Mon")
    .AddItem ("Tue")
    .AddItem ("Wed")
    .AddItem ("Thu")
    .AddItem ("Fri")
    .AddItem ("Sat")
    .AddItem ("Sun")
End With

End Sub
```

If the email is generated correctly, you may comment/remove the line .Display and uncomment the line .Send to send the email without displaying it on the screen.

Comment: Hi sktneer, thank you so much..it's now working. I wanted to be the Rest Days to be in dual column in my sheet like Column B and C.